Why doesn't F# inline this inner function?
I have this active pattern:
    [<return: Struct>]
    let (|Integer|_|) self =
        let rec loop acc (isNegative: bool) self =
            match self with 
            | C(digit, tail) when (Char.IsDigit digit) -> loop (acc * 10UL + (uint64 digit - uint64 '0')) isNegative tail
            | tail -> ValueSome struct(struct(acc, isNegative), tail)
        match self with
        | C('-', (C(digit, _) as tail)) when digit |> Char.IsDigit -> loop 0UL true tail
        | C('+', (C(digit, _) as tail)) when digit |> Char.IsDigit -> loop 0UL false tail
        | C(digit, _) as tail when digit |> Char.IsDigit -> loop 0UL false tail 
        | _ -> ValueNone

Loop is tail-recursive, and it shows up as such when I inspect the decompiled IL code (it gets turned into a while block). However, I'd expect the function call to loop to be simply turned into a goto-esque code block. But, in the decompiled code, I see this:
if (char.IsDigit(valueTuple.Item1))
{
    valueTuple = fsharpValueOption2.get_Item();
    tail = valueTuple.Item2;
    valueTuple = fsharpValueOption3.get_Item();
    digit = valueTuple.Item1;
    return Token.loop@16(0UL, true, tail);
}
break;

And I can see Token.loop@16 being defined as an actual function as well.
Shouldn't this simply get turned into a goto + while? Why isn't the function getting optimised away? Is it because of the two branches in the 'match' inside the outer function?
I tried defining loop as inline and recursive, but the compiler gives me an error.

But you're calling loop in three places. Would you expect it to be inlined thrice?

Couldn't it be turned into a label and then have each branch of the "match" set the values of the variables acc, isNegative, self, and then jump to the label?

Well sure, it could, but why? A label with parameters is literally a function.

Note also that the generated IL is not always the 'final' version of the code that will be executed or compiled on the fly. The JIT can make other optimisations. For example, try writing a tail-recursive (with continuation) version of a very simple function, such as the factorial, and then write a new factorial function that is implemented in an imperative and mutable style. Look at the generated code (with Compiler Explorer for example) and you'll see that the body of each of the functions is the same.
